# How to solve a forEach loop with a TypeError?

Tags: javascript, foreach, typeerror

It is showing:

> TypeError - cannot read property of undefined.

What's the problem here?

```
calcTotal: function(type) {
    sum = 0;
    data.allItems[type].forEach(function() {
        sum += data.totals[type];
        data.totals[type] = data.totals[type] + sum;
        tbudget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp;
        console.log(tbudget);
    }
)
},
```

Comment: It's not clear from what you've posted where the error is coming from. But your `forEach` is not really right. You need to pass the value to the function: `data.allItems[type].forEach(function(someType)` then you get each item (named `someType`) in the body.

Comment: For starters, post the specific error message not parts of it. It also tells you what line is affected which you have also ignored

Comment: The error message should tell you which property.  Whatever object you are trying to retrieve that property from, is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your `forEach` callback should have some arguments. Here is the format, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) { /*...*/ }
```

I don't know exactly what your "data" array looks like, but at least some of your references inside your `forEach` are almost certainly supposed to be looking at each array member, and not the `data` array itself. For example, I'm guessing your sum should be looking at each member, something like this maybe, if each member has a `totals` property containing various `type`s:

```
calcTotal: function(type) {
    sum = 0;
    data.allItems[type].forEach(function(item) {
        sum += item.totals[type];
        // ...
    }
)
},
```